# Does the addition of a library affect the app version?

Tags: android, version, libraries

After adding an external library, I can not install the app from Android Studio anymore.

I receive this message :

> Installation failed since the device already has a newer version of this application. In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the
>   existing application.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Since I did not change the gradle app version, I was wondering if the addition of a library could have changed the app version; and if so, how can that be avoided? Obs : Removing the library removes the problem too, but this is not a valid solution.

Comment: @H.Brooks I am using Maven. Why Android Studio takes into account the library version and not the app version?

Comment: The library gradle has nothing to do with your app's version. The error is saying that the version on your device is newer than the one you are trying to run now